# Laravel Echo + Laravel Passport + CORS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-echo

Lately I've encountered an error with authentication in laravel-echo-server.

I've managed to set up an application with Laravel Passport + Vue.js, and endpoints protected by `auth:api` **middleware** working just fine.

However, when I try to authenticated user with Laravel Echo, I'm getting 405 exception in the log of **laravel-echo-server**.

In order to add authentication to the `api` endpoint of laravel-echo-server, I've changed the contents of **BroadcastServiceProvider.php** to
`Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth:api']);` and here is how my **laravel-echo-server.json** file looks like

```
{
  "authHost": "http://192.168.225.128",
  "authEndpoint": "/api/broadcasting/auth",
  "clients": [
    {
      "appId": "APP_ID",
      "key": "APP_KEY"
    }
  ],
  "database": "redis",
  "databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
      "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
  },
  "devMode": true,
  "host": null,
  "port": "3389",
  "protocol": "http",
  "sslCertPath": "",
  "sslKeyPath": "",
  "sslCertChainPath": "",
  "sslPassphrase": "",
  "apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "http://192.168.225.128",
    "allowMethods": "OPTIONS, GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
  }
}
```

And this is how the echo server is configured from within the Vue.js app:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
const io = require('socket.io-client');
import store from '~/store';
window.io = io;

if (typeof io !== undefined) {
    let authenticationToken = store.getters['account/token'];
    let authenticated = store.getters['account/authenticated'];

    let echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: window.location.hostname + ':3389',
        auth: {
            headers: {
                Authorization: (authenticated) ? 'Bearer ' + authenticationToken : ''
            }
        }
    });
    window.Echo = echo;
    if (! Vue.hasOwnProperty('$echo')) {
        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$echo', {
            get() {
                return echo;
        }
        });
    }
    if (! Vue.hasOwnProperty('$io')) {
        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$io', {
            get() {
                return io;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Given the fact that **laravel-echo-server** spits out the 405 error, that means that all the data passed to the subscription service is correct, however, for some reason I'm getting method not allowed in the **laravel-echo-server** error log.

For clarification, I'm attaching [the log itself](https://pastebin.com/dHF1Ep2t).

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that broadcast routes are not being linked.

You need to un-comment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in config/app.php.

You can confirm then when you run `php artisan route:list` and  api/broadcasting/auth should appear there.